# terraform create AWS IAM user, with keys and create EC2 then set values of the keys in .aws/credential file in same EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a terraform script which is creating AWS IAM user with secret key and access key id. Same script is also creating AWS EC2.
now where I am getting stuck is in to set those keys in ~/.aws/credential file(like aws configure does) in EC2.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not the recommended solution. If you want to grant any access to your EC2 instances then do so via IAM `Roles` rather than keys. You have to attach a Role with permissions to your EC2 and it can call other services same like it would do from AWS profile (using keys).

Reference to how to achieve this in Terraform: https://skundunotes.com/2021/11/16/attach-iam-role-to-aws-ec2-instance-using-terraform/